# First-order interpolation inequalities with weights by L.Caffarelli, R.Kohn and L.Nirenberg

Tags: reference-request, sobolev-spaces, interpolation, differential-inequalities

L. Caffarelli, R. Kohn and L. Nirenberg showed in [this article](http://www.numdam.org/item/CM_1984__53_3_259_0.pdf) that, under some conditions, the following weighted interpolation inequality is valid

THEOREM: There exists a positive constant $C$ such that the following inequality holds for all $u \in C_0^{\infty} ( \mathbb{R}^n )$
$$\||x|^{\gamma} u\|_{L^r}\leq C \| |x|^{\alpha}|Du| \|^{a}_{L^p}\| |x|^{\beta}u \|^{1-a}_{L^q}$$
if and only if the following relations hold:
$$\dfrac{1}{r}+\dfrac{\gamma}{n} = a \left( \dfrac{1}{p}+ \dfrac{\alpha-1}{n}\right)+(1-a)\left( \dfrac{1}{q}+ \dfrac{\beta}{n}\right)$$
( this is dimensional balance ),
$$ 0 \leq \alpha-\sigma \mbox{ if } a>0$$
and
$$\alpha -\sigma\leq 1 \mbox{ if } a>0 \mbox{ and } \dfrac{1}{p}+\dfrac{\alpha-1}{n} = \dfrac{1}{r}+\dfrac{\gamma}{n}. $$
Here: $\gamma = a \alpha+(1-a)\beta.$

It caught my attention that requires that $u$ belong to the class $C_0^{\infty} ( \mathbb{R}^n )$.  I wonder if there has been any progress on this inequality and if there is a version that requires less of the function? For example some version that just asks that $u \in C_0^{m} ( \mathbb{R}^n )$, $m<\infty$. Does anyone know of an article that shows this?

Comment: It should be that the inequality holds also for any function $u$ which can be approximated strongly, in the norms on the right-hand side of the inequality, by $C^\infty_0$ functions.